# Android okhttp - POST request: Problems converting response to proper JSONArray

Tags: android, okhttp

I usually use `loopj` `AsyncHttpClient` for APIs but unfortunately it's not working on older Android APIs using https so I have to use okhttp instead.

This is the code:

```
val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
    .add("lastid", lastID.toString())
    .add("gal", gal)
    .build()
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("$domain/bla.php")
    .post(formBody)
    .build()

client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
    if (!response.isSuccessful){
        Log.d(tagg,"Unexpected code $response")
    }

    val myResponse = JSONArray(response.body!!.string())

    Log.d(tagg, myResponse.toString())

    setMemes(myResponse, gal)
}
```

Sometimes it works, the JSONArray gets parsed inside `setMemes` but sometimes it doesn't! The log ALWAYS shows the JSONArray though. So I'm guessing there is something wrong with the way the response is getting converted to JSONArray. It's NEVER a problem doing it with `AsyncHttpClient` because you don't have to do any extra steps to retrieving the JSONArray like converting

Is there a PROPER way getting JSONArray with okhttp which works every time and not randomly??

**EDIT1:**

This is the JSONArray after using loopj (doesn't fit completely in logcat):

```
2020-06-21 16:07:14.605 22393-22533/? D/pikabo: [{"id":"140","title":"That must hurt after a while","pic":"atYsvcQx_gif_38.mp4","size":"320|240","userid":"17","nickname":"Lolhunt42","commentcount":"5","time":"1592414298","secondsago":334138,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"4","votedown":"0"},{"id":"139","title":"","pic":"hWM9COQ180.jpg","size":"460|355","userid":"17","nickname":"Lolhunt42","commentcount":"0","time":"1592409945","secondsago":338491,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"138","title":"","pic":"VHyNissF49.jpg","size":"800|819","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592348577","secondsago":399859,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"137","title":"Just like my dog lmao","pic":"RwuTkylV52.jpg","size":"852|986","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592344259","secondsago":404177,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"134","title":"","pic":"GvXyE6Gw28.jpg","size":"800|874","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592271317","secondsago":477119,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"133","title":"","pic":"jNq4uvqV30.jpg","size":"700|546","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592271315","secondsago":477121,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"132","title":"","pic":"HCtosYx489.jpg","size":"716|770","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592271312","secondsago":477124,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"8","votedown":"1"},{"id":"131","title":"","pic":"NrNPzY7B98.jpg","size":"362|489","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592269295","secondsago":479141,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"130","title":"","pic":"3MMU123B32.jpg","size":"640|669","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592269292","secondsago":479144,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"129","title":"","pic":"HaHOC6W497.jpg","size":"720|922","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268759","secondsago":479677,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"0","votedown":"0"},{"id":"128","title":"","pic":"kjVaL1zC85.jpg","size":"720|703","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268756","secondsago":479680,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"127","title":"","pic":"3g3YXzqM69.jpg","size":"700|607","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268754","secondsago":479682,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"126","title":"","pic":"cLGHi5YI19.jpg","size":"480|693","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268752","secondsago":479684,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"125","title":"","pic":"UNV5bIVc26.jpg","size":"711|738","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268747","secondsago":479689,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"124","title":"","pic":"x6zdb4SR02.jpg","size":"700|711","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592265141","secondsago":483295,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"123","title":"","pic":"8UvBlGly68.jpg","size":"500|700","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592265133","secondsago":483303,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"118","title":"Better than masks","pic":"I1Inh92348.jpg","size":"800|900","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1591727637","secondsago":1020799,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"107","title":"","pic":"jjMlP6Sf29.jpg","size":"719|845","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount
```

and this using okhttp:

```
2020-06-21 16:07:24.576 22393-22536/? D/pikabo: [{"id":"140","title":"That must hurt after a while","pic":"atYsvcQx_gif_38.mp4","size":"320|240","userid":"17","nickname":"Lolhunt42","commentcount":"5","time":"1592414298","secondsago":334148,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"4","votedown":"0"},{"id":"139","title":"","pic":"hWM9COQ180.jpg","size":"460|355","userid":"17","nickname":"Lolhunt42","commentcount":"0","time":"1592409945","secondsago":338501,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"138","title":"","pic":"VHyNissF49.jpg","size":"800|819","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592348577","secondsago":399869,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"137","title":"Just like my dog lmao","pic":"RwuTkylV52.jpg","size":"852|986","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592344259","secondsago":404187,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"134","title":"","pic":"GvXyE6Gw28.jpg","size":"800|874","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592271317","secondsago":477129,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"133","title":"","pic":"jNq4uvqV30.jpg","size":"700|546","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592271315","secondsago":477131,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"132","title":"","pic":"HCtosYx489.jpg","size":"716|770","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592271312","secondsago":477134,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"8","votedown":"1"},{"id":"131","title":"","pic":"NrNPzY7B98.jpg","size":"362|489","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592269295","secondsago":479151,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"130","title":"","pic":"3MMU123B32.jpg","size":"640|669","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"1","time":"1592269292","secondsago":479154,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"129","title":"","pic":"HaHOC6W497.jpg","size":"720|922","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268759","secondsago":479687,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"0","votedown":"0"},{"id":"128","title":"","pic":"kjVaL1zC85.jpg","size":"720|703","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268756","secondsago":479690,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"127","title":"","pic":"3g3YXzqM69.jpg","size":"700|607","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268754","secondsago":479692,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"126","title":"","pic":"cLGHi5YI19.jpg","size":"480|693","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268752","secondsago":479694,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"125","title":"","pic":"UNV5bIVc26.jpg","size":"711|738","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592268747","secondsago":479699,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"124","title":"","pic":"x6zdb4SR02.jpg","size":"700|711","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592265141","secondsago":483305,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"2","votedown":"0"},{"id":"123","title":"","pic":"8UvBlGly68.jpg","size":"500|700","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1592265133","secondsago":483313,"checked":"1","liked":0,"disliked":0,"voteup":"1","votedown":"0"},{"id":"118","title":"Better than masks","pic":"I1Inh92348.jpg","size":"800|900","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount":"0","time":"1591727637","secondsago":1020809,"checked":"1","liked":1,"disliked":0,"voteup":"3","votedown":"0"},{"id":"107","title":"","pic":"jjMlP6Sf29.jpg","size":"719|845","userid":"14","nickname":"Memetron1337","commentcount
```

It looks absolutely identical

Comment: It is most likely the response you are getting that differs in some way, your best option is to analyse the json that comes in when it works and when it doesnt and see what the difference is. Hard to say without seeing any of your json.

Comment: I have added the jsonarray to the question